Fredholm Property for Elliptic Operator
Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$ be a bounded domain with $C^2$-boundary, and $L:H^1_0(\Omega)\to H^{-1}(\Omega)$ be a uniform elliptic operator. Given $f\in H^{-1}(\Omega)$, we want to solve
$$(\ast)\begin{cases}
Lu=f\\
u|_{\partial\Omega}=0
\end{cases}$$
Now, Fredholm Alternative applies only to the case when $f\in L^2(\Omega)\subset H^{-1}(\Omega)$. Together with boundary regularity, we have $u\in H^2(\Omega)$ if it solves $(\ast)$ with $f\in L^2(\Omega)$.
Does that mean that $L$ is a Fredholm operator of index $0$ when $L$ is considered to be an operator $L:H^2(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega)$?
What about $L:H^1_0(\Omega)\to H^{-1}(\Omega)$? Does Fredholm Alternative applies for $f\in H^{-1}(\Omega)$?
